# How can I return self and another variable in a python class method while method chaining?

Tags: python

I understand what I am asking here is probably not the best code design, but the reason for me asking is strictly academic. I am trying to understand how to make this concept work.

Typically, I will return `self` from a class method so that the following methods can be chained together. My understanding is by returning self, I am simply returning an instance of the class, for the following methods to work on.

But in this case, I am trying to figure out how to return both `self` and another value from the method. The idea is if I do not want to chain, or I do not call any class attributes, I want to retrieve the data from the method being called.

Consider this example:

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hold = None

    def methoda(self):
        self.hold = 'lol'
        return self, 'lol'

    def newmethod(self):
        self.hold = self.hold * 2
        return self, 2

t = Test()
t.methoda().newmethod()
print(t.hold)
```

In this case, I will get an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'newmethod'` which is to be expected because the `methoda` method is returning a tuple which does not have any methods or attributes called `newmethod`.

My question is not about unpacking multiple returns, but more about how can I continue to chain methods when the preceding methods are returning multiple values. I also understand that I can control the methods return with an argument to it, but that is not what I am trying to do.

As mentioned previously, I do realize this is probably a bad question, and I am happy to delete the post if the question doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Hi @Chris. As I mentioned in the post, I am not trying to accomplish anything with the code. It is more of a learning question because I couldnt find any answers to it. The thought here is that if i wanted to keep chaining, then the class instance gets passed around, but if i wanted to get the value of the last chained method, then I can get it out instead of calling an attribute that is holding that value.

Comment: "then I can get it out instead of calling an attribute that is holding that value"—just use the attribute that is holding that value.

Comment: Either you return an instance of your class or you return a tuple. I don't see how you can chain the result if it isn't simply an instance of your class. You could of course modify `self` so that it has an attribute that keeps track of the other datum that you would want to keep track of, but you seem to have something else in mind.

Comment: @Chris yes, you are right. But again, as I mentioned in the OP, I am aware that I can call the holding attribute, but that that is not what I am trying to do. 
JohnColeman, yes, that has been my experience with this also. Its one or the other. But just curious if this was even possible. I realize this isnt the typical how do I solve a numpy problem question, so thats why I was very guarded when posting the question.

Comment: I'm still confused about why you would ever do this. Write methods that each do one thing. A method that returns `2` _shouldn't_ be chainable. And it's a good idea to write idiomatic code that won't surprise people when they use it.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a class that extends `tuple` in much the same way that something like a `defaultdict` extends `dictionary`. This not-just-a-tuple could perhaps process the method call dynamically (though I am not sure how, or even why). Maybe something which simultaneously inherits from the class you are defining and from `tuple`.

Comment: @Chris, again, the question is not WHY someone would do this, because again, as stated in the OP, i fully realize this is not typical. The question is IF it could be done. And if not, then I understand. To me this is more of a puzzle that must have a solution.

Comment: I tend to set something like `self.tmp = x` to bind the result to the instance and return self.  Thing is, you are either chaining on the return or looking at the result, it’s hard to do both, as you point out.  The tmp is there for you to use if you don’t chain.  Of course thread safety and all sorts of other considerations make this an iffy approach, but I use it without too many downsides on custom unittest assert methods.  But, no, its not quite what you asked.  You could also look at Rust’s specialized success/result return type for ideas.

Comment: @JLPeyret you are very right. What I am asking it really unconventional. But now this has become a curiosity. I willl check out the Rust return types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the suggestion by @JohnColeman, you can return a special tuple with attribute lookup delegated to your object if it is not a normal tuple attribute.  That way it acts like a normal tuple except when you are chaining methods.

You can implement this as follows:

```py
class ChainResult(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return super(ChainResult, cls).__new__(cls, args)
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(super(), name)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(super().__getitem__(0), name)


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hold = None

    def methoda(self):
        self.hold = 'lol'
        return ChainResult(self, 'lol')

    def newmethod(self):
        self.hold = self.hold * 2
        return ChainResult(self, 2)
```

Testing:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.methoda().newmethod()
>>> print(t.hold)
lollol
```

The returned result does indeed act as a tuple:

```py
>>> t, res = t.methoda().newmethod()
>>> print(res)
2
>>> print(isinstance(t.methoda().newmethod(), tuple))
True
```

---

You could imagine all sorts of semantics with this, such as forwarding the returned values to the next method in the chain using closure:

```
class ChainResult(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return super(ChainResult, cls).__new__(cls, args)
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(super(), name)
        except AttributeError:
            attr = getattr(super().__getitem__(0), name)
            if callable(attr):
                chain_results = super().__getitem__(slice(1, None))
                return lambda *args, **kw: attr(*(chain_results+args), **kw)
            else:
                return attr
```

For example,

```py
class Test:
    ...
    def methodb(self, *args):
        print(*args)
```

would produce

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.methoda().methodb('catz')
lol catz
```

---

It would be nice if you could make ChainResults invisible.  You can almost do it by initializing the tuple base class with the normal results and saving your object in a separate attribute used only for chaining.  Then use a class decorator that wraps every method with `ChainResults(self, self.method(*args, **kw))`.  It will work okay for methods that return a tuple but a single value return will act like a length 1 tuple, so you will need something like `obj.method()[0]` or `result, = obj.method()` to work with it.  I played a bit with delegating to tuple for a multiple return or to the value itself for a single return; maybe it could be made to work but it introduces so many ambiguities that I doubt it could work well.

Comment: This is a really clever solution!